Error with gather localization - Unreal Engine
I’m trying to gather my localization. I’m getting this error and I don’t know what it means.

I would just like to have a solution. What do you recommend doing? I use Lyra Unreal Engine.
What I want is to be able to see the new texts that I added in the different UI Widgets, because there were many.

Have you tried restarting UnrealEd and then directly going into the localization, without opening any other assets?

@MaxPlay
I don't know how to do that, by restart UnrealEd do you mean opening and closing UE5?

UnrealEd is the tool that you use to author an unreal project. UE5 is the game engine underneath. The editor is not the engine. But yes, I mean close the editor and restart it and without opening any assets go straight into localization and retry.

Honestly, I don't think that's the solution because I do restart my UE5. What do you recommmend me to do? As I told you, I created a new button and I want to translate it into other languages, the text to translate it does not appear. I thought about including it manually in the localization files, but it is very laborious.

In my experience, restarting the editor does fix a lot of things with "GatherText". I don't know why. That's what I suggested. If you have marked the text as localizable (it is by default) and run GatherText it should show up. This question either needs more information, or you should visit the unreal forums for a more in-depth discussion. I'm sorry, I couldn't help you so far.

I just want to translate manually, word by word.
I thought I should have put it in the .po file and then compiled it. But I don't know where or if it is possible.

In Localization Dashboard under Gather from Packages, under Collections, delete Audit_InCook, now it will work.
